# Search a word in file and replace in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to replace word "a" to "red" in a.text files. I want to edit the same file so I tried this code but it does not work. Where am I going wrong?

```
@files=glob("a.txt");
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    open(IN,$file) or die $!;
    <IN>;
    while(<IN>)
    {
       $_=~s/a/red/g;
       print IN $file;
    }

   close(IN)
}
```

Comment: Suggested answer below is one way to do it. But you are attempting to read and write to a file at the same time. You can append to a file, but I don't think perl provides a way to read and write the same time (atleast not out of the box). One other suggestion is to use 'use strict' clause. Makes your perl scripts robust and readable.

Comment: It sort of does via `-i` and `$^I` or `open` with `<+`. But it's a bit more complex than that.

Comment: You can't `print` to a filehandle that is only open for reading. If you had `use warnings` in your code, then Perl would have told you that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest it's probably easier to use perl in `sed` mode:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/a/red/g' *.txt
```

`-i` is inplace edit (`-i.bak` saves the old as `.bak` - `-i` without a specifier doesn't create a backup - this is often not a good idea).

`-p` creates a loop that iterates all the files specified one line at a time (`$_`), applying whatever code is specified by `-e` before printing that line. In this case - `s///` applies a sed-style patttern replacement to `$_`, so this runs a search and replace over every `.txt` file.

Perl uses `<ARVG>` or `<>` to do some magic - it checks if you specify files on your command line - if you do, it opens them and iterates them. If you don't, it reads from `STDIN`.

So you can also do:

```
 somecommand.sh | perl -i.bak -p -e 's/a/red/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using same filehandle to write which you have used for open the file to reading. Open the same file for write mode and then write.

Always use lexical filehandle and three arguments to open a file. Here is your modified code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = glob("a.txt");
my @data;
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    open my $fhin, "<", $file or die $!;
    <$fhin>;
    while(<$fhin>)
    {
        $_ =~ s/\ba\b/red/g;
        push @data, $_;
    }
    open my $fhw, ">", $file or die "Couldn't modify file: $!";
    print $fhw @data;
    close $fhw;
}
```

Here is another way (read whole file in a scalar):

```
foreach my $file (glob "/path/to/dir/a.txt")
{
    #read whole file in a scalar
    my $data = do {
        local $/ = undef;
        open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
        <$fh>;
    };
    $data =~ s/\ba\b/red/g; #replace a with red,

    #modify the file
    open my $fhw, ">", $file or die "Couldn't modify file: $!";
    print $fhw $data;
    close $fhw;
}
```

Comment: @reinierpost: Might be OP wants use Perl. OP is trying to write a script in Perl, thats why I use Perl.

Comment: I think you should be able open then unlink and write back - this is effectively what `-i` does.